# Are there any known approaches to define application specific messages?

Tags: tcp, udp, ipc, messaging, communication

I have a system where embedded devices communicate with each other. Each device may not communicate with every other device in the network. I want to define message types for my system. The messages might be sent with TCP/IP or UDP or another protocol. There are couple of fields in this message, such as `from`, `to` and `data` itself. Are there any well-known approaches or guides to define length of such fields, fields to include and etc? I am not sure whether the question is too broad or not.

Example:

| `from` (1B) | `to` (1B) | `data` (nB) |

Note that B stands for byte.

Comment: You definitely should add context to the question. What's the purpose of your protocol? What kind of devices we are taking about? Etc.

Comment: So the messages are sent using multiple transfer protocols, depending on the device that sends them? Are you sending all messages in the same format (JSON, XML, etc.)?

Comment: The application data is same regardless of transport and below layers. There are multiple transport (or other) layer protocols.

Answer (score 2):

There are no fixed ways or predefined standards. There are protocols, either use a predefined protocols or design your custom protocols as you mentioned in the last part of your question. It could be application specific protocol structure or based on the channel limitations. Moreover the question should be a bit more specific or detailed for a better suggestion. Have a look at the protocol definitions of few famous protocols like USB, MQTT, HTTP, etc to give you a better idea.